# Joining 2 tables that use LIKE as a common identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
wp_rg_lead_detail:    

id       lead_id    form_id    field_number    value
=====================================================
166649   2579       4          235             batman
167324   2602       4          235             batman
168439   2579       4          235             kelsey
169221   2836       4          235             batman

wp_rg_incomplete_submissions:

uuid                form_id   submission
=======================================================================
fds4389dsd2kjd      4         JSON entry that doesn't contain 'kelsey
ciwod2938slsck      4         JSON entry that contains 'kelsey
392copaa234jfl      4         JSON entry that doesn't contain 'kelsey
```

What I want to do is grab the record that:

- has the word 'kelsey' in *wp_rg_incomplete_submissions.submission*
- has a  *wp_rg_incomplete_submissions.form_id* of 4
- has the word 'kelsey' as a *value* in *wp_rg_lead_detail*
- and the *lead_id* for that entry in *wp_rg_lead_details* should also have the word 'batman' for a *value*.

The only identifier between the two tables is the word 'kelsey'. But where it exists in *wp_rg_lead_detail*, that *lead_id* must also have an entry with the *value* of 'batman'.

I have tried subqueries and joins, and I'm getting nowhere.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**
From the feedback below, it sounds like I should create an alias and then join them where that exists in both.  Here's where I'm at:

```
SELECT *, 'kelsey' AS myvalue
   FROM `wp_rg_lead_detail`
WHERE (`value` LIKE 'batman'
   OR `value` LIKE 'kelsey') 
   AND `form_id` = 4
GROUP BY `lead_id`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I think somehow I need to join this where the LIKE uses myvalue:

```
SELECT *, uuid 
   FROM `wp_rg_incomplete_submissions` 
WHERE `form_id` = 4 
   AND `submission` LIKE concat_ws(";", "%", myvalue, "%")
```

**UPDATE #2**

After continuing to struggle with this, I've come up with:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_rg_lead_detail 
INNER JOIN wp_rg_incomplete_submissions ON wp_rg_lead_detail.value 
LIKE CONCAT('%', wp_rg_incomplete_submissions.submission, '%')
WHERE wp_rg_lead_detail.value = 'kelsey'
```

I know I'm doing something wrong because there are no results.  But I feel it is much closer than where I started from.

Comment: Which way (left, right...) do you want to join the tables?

Comment: I would think you can select from each table what you want, but can't figure out how to join them. You may want to include a dummy column on both tables so that you can join on it i.e `'kelsey' as Match`.

Comment: @Confuzing Thanks.  I have added some information to my question based on the idea you provided.  Not sure that I'm moving in the right direction or not.

Answer (score 2):

So here is what I came up with, not vouching for it's efficiency as I don't write much SQL.

```
SELECT *
  FROM submissions
  JOIN (SELECT detail.*
          FROM detail
          JOIN detail detail2
            ON detail2.lead_id = detail.lead_id
         WHERE detail.value = 'kelsey'
           AND detail2.value = 'batman'
       ) as detailjoin
    ON detailjoin.form_id = submissions.form_id
 WHERE submissions.submission LIKE '%kelsey%'
   AND submissions.form_id = 4;
```

Which from you data set returns:

```
'ciwod2938slsck'  4  'JSON with kelsey'   168439     2579   4   235  'kelsey'
```

So to break it down, the inner join query gets all `detail` rows that have `'kelsey'` as a `value` where that `lead_id` also exists in a row with a `'batman'` `value`.

The outer query selects all rows with `form_id` of `4` and `'kelsey'` in `submission`

Then it simply joins the two on `form_id = form_id`.

I believe this does what you needed although with the small data set not positive.